# Summarizing data without dupes

Tags: sql

I have some claims data from providers with dupes.  My dupes are based on combining multiple columns (member_id + provider_id + claimDate + CPT). I would like to summarize the data by State and by CPT and sum the paid amt for unique claims only.  Here is the data table and the desired result:

[image]

Here is my shot at this:

```
SELECT
  State
 ,CPT
 ,SUM(paid)
FROM
  Claims
GROUP BY
  FS
 ,CPT;
```

Unfortunately, this sums all the dupe rows as well.  How do I exclude the dupe rows when summarizing by State and by CPT?

Thanks

Comment: You can have a sub query thats a self join and checks for count =1, and them sum in the outer query

Comment: What is `FS` field? There's no such field in your table.

Comment: By the way, your result table is incorrect because it's missing third row.

Answer (score 1):

First deduplicate (Select Distinct), then group over the results from that:

```
Select   State, CPT, sum(paid) 
From     ( Select Distinct member_id, provider_id, claimdate, State, CPT, paid From Claims)
Group By State, CPT
```

Note that this will only work if the amounts for the two claims are also the same, otherwise they will be counted as two.

Comment: How would I change your from statement if it's joint statement.  Here is my From Statement:                                                                                                        

From ((Claims inner join ClaimDetails ON Claims.ClmID =ClaimDetails.ClmID) left join Rate ON  (ClaimDetails.CR = Rate.CR) AND (ClaimDetails.CPT = Rate.CPT)) Left Join Claims2 on ClaimDetails.ClmID = Claims2.ClmID

Comment: You forgot claimdate

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @claims table
(
    member_id   int ,
    provider_id varchar(10),
    claimDate   date,
    CPT         varchar(10),
    [State]     char(2),
    Paid        numeric
);

insert into @claims values
(123, 'abc', '2018-01-01', 'D11', 'NY', 10),
(123, 'abc', '2018-01-01', 'D11', 'NY', 10),
(123, 'abc', '2018-01-02', 'D11', 'NY', 5),
(555, 'xyz', '2018-01-05', '01T', 'NJ', 39),
(555, 'xyz', '2018-01-05', '01T', 'NJ', 39),
(666, 'xyz', '2018-01-05', 'V93', 'NJ', 11);

select [State], CPT, TheSum
from
(
    select *,
           RowNum = row_number() over (partition by member_id, provider_id, claimDate, CPT
                                       order by member_id),
           TheSum = sum(Paid) over (partition by member_id, provider_id, claimDate, CPT
                                    order by member_id)
    from @claims
) x
where x.RowNum = 1;
```